# Simplify copy-paste process with a Helper class

Tags: java, performance

I am working on a project and I have a question. I use this code in 50% of classes.

```
public sendMessage disableNotification(boolean disableNotification) {
    this.disableNotification = disableNotification;

    return this;
}
```

Is there a method of inheritance with a hypothetical class `Helper` that allows me to write the method only one time?

The only thing that changes in every class is the Object. For example, this is `sendMessage` others can be `sendAudio`. Can I simplify this copy-paste process?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following. Can you share a bit more code, and highlight where you'd like to avoid copy-pasting?

Comment: Just by looking at this code, I doubt it's possible to tell. The only thing I'm sure about here is that Java naming conventions aren't being followed. By those conventions, class name should start with uppercase character.

Comment: Apart from the naming convention issue, based on the code that you have shared, it seems to be me that you shouldn't need "sendMessage/SendMessage" as a return type since you are returning "this" which means this method is in the "SendMessage" class itself. You should never have to return "this" from here, since the calling code would already have a reference to the object.

Comment: @AnkurChrungoo, unless it's a "builder" class, then it's useful to chain method calls like that.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov agreed!

Comment: @M.Prokhorov thanks for suggestion

Comment: @kratess, I didn't suggest anything other than an implied suggestion to follow naming conventions. It's still not clear what is it exactly that you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are looking for abstract class.

```
abstract class  Helper {
    private boolean disableNotification;

    public Helper disableNotification(boolean disableNotification) {
        this.disableNotification = disableNotification;
        return this;
    }
}

class sendMessage extends Helper {

}

class sendAudio extends Helper {

}

class Test {
    public static void Test() {
        Helper sendMessage = new sendMessage();
        Helper helper = sendMessage.disableNotification(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution will not look pretty if `sendAudio` has other methods, and you try to call them after calling `disableNotification`.

Comment: I too am not sure about the intent, behind the question, the answer is just to hint toward abstract class concept.

Comment: Your code worked so thank you so much. I have another question. It is possible to change "Helper helper = ..." to the no-abstract class like "sendMessage message = ..."?

Comment: it is possible try this, sendMessage message = (sendMessage)sendMessage.disableNotification(true);

Comment: Okay... without (sendMessage) there is a method?

Comment: @kartess can you please elaborate.

Comment: Exists a way to add methods of main class so "sendMessage" after apply a method from abstract class? "sendMessage.disableNotification(true)" i cannot add other methods from class "sendMessage"

Comment: once "sendMessage.disableNotification(true)" is called, you shouldn't be able to call any other methods of "sendMessage". So, say you have another method "sendMessage.doWork() ", you shouldn't be able to call that, is it right?

Comment: That's exactly what I was talking about when saying it's not gonna be pretty.

Answer (score 0):

```
abstract class Helper {
  private boolean disableNotification;

  public Helper disableNotification(boolean disableNotification) {
    this.disableNotification = disableNotification;
    return this;
  }
}

class sendMessage extends Helper {
}

class Test {
  public static void Test() {
    Helper sendMessage = new sendMessage();
    Helper helper = sendMessage.disableNotification(true);
  }
}
```